# How do I get only one selection on multiple QListViews?

Tags: c++, qt

I have got the following program:

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class MainWindow : public QDialog {
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
QVBoxLayout layout;

QListView view1, view2, view3;

QStandardItemModel model1, model2, model3;

QStandardItem item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    item1 {"Item 1"},
    item2 {"Item 2"},
    item3 {"Item 3"},
    item4 {"Item 4"},
    item5 {"Item 5"},
    item6 {"Item 6"}
{
    model1.appendColumn({&item1, &item2});
    model2.appendColumn({&item3, &item4});
    model3.appendColumn({&item5, &item6});

    view1.setModel(&model1);
    view2.setModel(&model2);
    view3.setModel(&model3);

    layout.addWidget(&view1);
    layout.addWidget(&view2);
    layout.addWidget(&view3);

    this->setLayout(&layout);

    connect(view1.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            view2.selectionModel(), SLOT(reset()));
    connect(view1.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            view3.selectionModel(), SLOT(reset()));

    connect(view2.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            view1.selectionModel(), SLOT(reset()));
    connect(view2.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            view3.selectionModel(), SLOT(reset()));

    connect(view3.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            view2.selectionModel(), SLOT(reset()));
    connect(view3.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            view1.selectionModel(), SLOT(reset()));
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.exec();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**a.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = a
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
```

This was my attempt to create a `QDialog` that has multiple `QListViews` with different models in which **only one item can be selected at the same time**. It works if you simply click on different items, but once you click the `QListView` in an empty space and then click the item, multiple entries are selected. The selection is then only cleared if i either click the other `QListView` in an empty space, or minimize the dialog and activate it again.

What am I missing? Do i have to connect other `slots`/`signals`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `clearSelection` instead of `reset` seems to do the trick

Also, according to the docs [[1]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection), [[2]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#reset) it seems to be the more appropriate function for this.

Comment: Ouch, I just didnt use it, because it emits the selectionChanged signal, which I missused somewhere else in my project. Thank you very much ;-)

Comment: Just one thing i noticed: I will probably have to use something else than currentChanged, as it's still possible to select multiple entries. The clicked signal of QListView should do the trick.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop has a single selection mode. Maybe this works. I'd assume there is some way this can be done without doing it manually (inside one `QListView` I mean, not across multiple)

Comment: I think the single selection mode is the default, as I can only select one element in a QListView. There appareantly is no way to easily realize this problem without connecting the signal/slots manually. At least I didnt find anything on the web in a 2 hour search.